# Problems with starting chrome from a batch file

Tags: flash, google-chrome, command-line, screensaver, kiosk

I am trying to start chrome in windows 8.1 for a Kiosk

```
start "" chrome file:///C:/kiosk/kiosk.swf –kiosk –allow-file-access-from-files –incognito –enable-screensaver-extensions –kiosk-mode-screensaver-path file:///C:/kiosk/screensaver.swf
```

it is opening every one of the commandline options as if they are
separate pages. leaving only -kiosk works. but I need the screensave and the page to open up as well.

I have googled, and googled and I am still lost.
Any advice?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command is wrong:

```
start chrome --kiosk file:///C:/kiosk/kiosk.swf --allow-file-access-from-files --incognito --enable-screensaver-extensions --kiosk-mode-screensaver-path=file:///C:/kiosk/screensaver.swf
```

The main issues were with the command line switches (they all start with two hyphens not one), and the superfluous `""` at the beginning.

You also don't strictly need to use the `start` command; you can start Chrome by just calling the exe directly (e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe` or similar, depending on where you have it installed on your machine).